# Create view within actionresult mvc6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've downloaded Visual Studio 2015 and created an empty project. What I cannot work out is how do you create a new view from within IActionResult, in VS2013 you could right click and create it. But now there appears to be no option for this.

The only way I can do it, is to create the view manually.

Am I missing something simple

Comment: I just posted the same question

Comment: As of now there is no support for this in VS, but you could try the `Command Line Scaffolding` as mentioned here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/21/command-line-scaffolding-for-asp-net-vnext.aspx